# How can a solution of the time-independent Schrödinger equation evolve in space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I understand that if the Hamiltonian does not depend on the time, the [Schrödinger Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) becomes separable, so you get

$$
H \psi(x) = E \psi(x)
$$

and

$$
\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)\exp\left(-\frac{\imath E}{\hbar}t\right).
$$

But $-\frac{\imath E}{\hbar}t$ is a purely imaginary number, so
$$
\left|\exp\left(-\frac{\imath E}{\hbar}t\right)\right| = 1
$$

If that is correct, **then how can there be any probability density flow in time?** The $exp$ term is only changing the phase of $\psi$, but does not contribute anything to its absolute value.

What did I understand wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is only true if $\psi(x)$ is an **eigenstate** of $H$.

For some general $\psi(x)$ that is not an eigenstate (i.e. $H \psi(x) \ne E \psi(x)$), then $\Psi(x, t)$ will be more complicated than just the time independent wavefunction multiplied by a phase factor.

Answer (score 1):

The separable solutions are exactly the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian which are exactly the ones where the probability density does not change.

However you can have a flux or flow of probability even if the probability doesn't change.  This is like electromagnetism where you can have current floe through a wire even if the wire has no change of charge density.

For instance if you had a circular wire with now resistance it is possible to have a steady current flow in a circle even without and change in charge density.

Similarly you can have a probability current even if the probability density doesn't change.